# Using variable inside anonymous function .on

Tags: javascript, jquery, es6-class, twitch

so I don't have a lot of experiences in using classes with javascript and I'm facing a problem that is certainly easy to solve but I can't find the solution.

It's quite simple, I would like to have access to the variable this.gtaList inside the anonymous function of ".on()".

I know the solutions without using the classes, but since I force myself to use them in order to be able to use this code later, I'm facing a wall.

...

```
            success: function(streamList) { 
                     this.gtaList = [];
                     this.streamList = streamList

                for (let i = 0; i < this.streamList['data'].length; i++){

                    if(this.streamList['data'][i]['game_id'] == 32982){

                        this.gtaList.push(this.streamList['data'][i]['display_name'])
                                                                                                                   
                        this.img = $('<img id="thumbnail'+i+' " src="https://static- 
                        cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_'+this.streamList['data'][i] 
                        ['display_name']+'-300x200.jpg">')
                        .on("click", (function (index) { /* I want to use this.gtaList inside this 
                                                            function*/
                            
                            return function (e) { 
                                console.log(index)                                   
                                new Twitch.Embed("twitch-embed-main", {
                                    width: '80%',
                                    height: '80%',
                                    channel: this.gtaList[index],/* this.gtaList is undefined here */
                                    autoplay: false,
                                    layout: "video",
                                    parent: ["embed.example.com", "othersite.example.com"]
                                }); 
                            };
                        })(i));

                        $('#twitch-embed-low').append(this.img)    
                    }
                }
```

...

I hope I have been as clear as possible, in general I find it difficult to explain haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrow function `=>` instead so you can access  the `this` keyword properly

something like this:

```js
.on("click", index => { })
```